# To explain or to be explained

Tags: adjectives, passive-voice, objects, tough-movement

I have searched lots of websites to understand which one is correct in this sentence:

```
It is too hard to (be) explain(ed).
```

Some people say that after some adjectives called `tough` adjectives you can't use the passive form of verbs. I have heard from some native speakers that `It is too hard to be explained` is very strange to their ears. So I search on the Internet and I found that at least 14 million people think that `to be explained` is correct and they actually have used it.
I am sure that I am missing something here. Maybe they are used in different situations. But I couldn't find any real difference between them.

Any help is more than welcomed.

P.S: To further complicate the situation for a word like `pass`, when I searched it on the Internet, you can't really say "`Exam was too difficult to be passed`".

Comment: The phrase you're looking for is "_Tough_-Movement predicates", like _tough, easy, hard_; _Tough_-Movement is a rule that moves only direct objects from complement clauses. Notice that _Calculus is hard to explain_ is grammatical (_Tough_-Movement), while "Calculus is hard to be explained" is not. This isn't about _hard_ or about _Tough_-Movement; it's about the ***too `X` to `VP`*** construction, which means 'so `X` that `Not S`', and can select **either** subjects (_He's too short to reach the ceiling_) or objects (_He's too short to pick for the team_).

Answer (score 2):

[These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=too+tough+to+be+eaten%2Ctoo+tough+to+eat&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctoo%20tough%20to%20be%20eaten%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctoo%20tough%20to%20eat%3B%2Cc0) show that *... too tough to be eaten ...* and *... too tough to eat ...* are both used, but that the second variant, with the tough movement, is far the more common.

I'd say that *... too hard to be explained ...* is considered stylistically even less optimal. The [relevant Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=too+hard+to+be+explained%2Ctoo+hard+to+explain&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctoo%20hard%20to%20explain%3B%2Cc0) seem to confirm my suspicions.

*Too difficult to be explained* has a [very small following](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=too+difficult+to+be+explained%2Ctoo+difficult+to+explain&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctoo%20difficult%20to%20be%20explained%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctoo%20difficult%20to%20explain%3B%2Cc0).

[This Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tough_movement) looks at tough movemment.

Comment: So, the reason that I can't find a sentence like "exam was too hard to be passed" is that usually, kids use a sentence like this and they are using more modern forms of language.

Comment: Some phrases like 'to be eaten' or 'to be passed' or 'to be explained' aren't used in books anymore. But they are being used in everyday speaking.