# "hard to distinguish" or "hard to be distinguished"?

Tags: passive-voice, infinitives

Here is a phrase (slightly modified from the original) that I'd like to discuss.

> A) targeting small structures that are hard to distinguish

I have no doubt that this will convey what it means, but I think that the following is more "authentic" in terms of grammar:

> B) targeting small structures that are hard to be distinguished

Would you agree or not? Can you explain why grammatically?

I tried to explain why I think B is better, but I'm not sure now.

I think the problem can be simplified to the difference between the following examples:

> C) small structures are hard to distinguish
>
> D) small structures are hard to be distinguished

It's about what is the subject for the verb "distinguish". Please help!

Comment: If you dress the small structures up with a bow tie they will appear more distinguished.

Comment: The predicate adjectives _hard, easy, tough, difficult,_ and a few others govern a rule called _Tough_-movement, which correlates sentences like _Bill is easy to please_ and _To please Bill is easy_ (which is also related via Extraposition to _It is easy to please Bill_). Note that in all of these, it is the Direct Object of the infinitive that is moved to become subject of the main clause. _Tough_-Movement contrasts with Raising, which moves the **Subject** of an infinitive up to the main clause, as in _Bill seems to like his new job_ (_Bill_ is the subject of _like_).

Comment: Oh, and _Tough_-Movement doesn't allow passive infinitives: *_Bill was hard to be convinced; *Small structures are hard to be distinguished_. This is because Passive moves the object to become subject, but _Tough_-Movement moves the object up to the next clause. You can do one or the other but not both.

Comment: Thanks, @John Lawler. Yeah, I thought there was something special about the adjective "hard", but could not think of a named rule. I found a Wikipedia article about Tough Movement. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tough_movement

Comment: Does this answer your question? [To explain or to be explained](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/229711/to-explain-or-to-be-explained)