# Grammar confusion, why without -ed

Tags: grammar

I am confused with this sentence

"Convincing evidence to support this theory is hard to obtain"

In my opinion, shouldn't be the "obtain" is "obtained", because the sentence sounds like a passive sentence for me or my understanding might be wrong.
Please give some insight.

Thank you

Comment: "Obtained" would be incorrect. This is a construction that is used with some adjectives like *hard.* There is more about it in the comments on this question: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/491340/hard-to-distinguish-or-hard-to-be-distinguished

Comment: You would not say "to eated" or "to walked".

Comment: It's hard to know whether you think it should be "obtained" the simple past or the past participle, as they are the same, but yeah, basically what Hot Licks said. Either would be wrong, "I am happy to did it", "I am happy to done it", both wrong. In these constructions the verb has to stay in its infinitive form, "do".

Comment: Another related question: [How does the to infinitive work with adjectives like “wrong” and “wise”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/289775)