# It is an important thing to do or to be done?

Tags: grammaticality, tough-movement

Which one is correct? Can i use them interchangably and is there a common rule for such constructions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

*It is an important thing to do* contains an example of what *The Cambridge Grammar Of The English Language* (CGEL, p1255) calls a '*hollow non-finite clause*:

In its general introduction to the topic, the CGEL gives these examples (among others):

- The problem took her only a few minutes to solve.
- That he would do such a thing is hard to believe.
- You won't find these kids easy to teach.

According to the CGEL *"there are six constructions where hollow to-infinitivals are required or permitted*". The second of these constructions are those that "*are licensed by an attributive adjective"*. This construction type matches the sentence in question *It is an important thing to do*.

Among the examples given are:

- It's a difficult book to understand.
- That wasn't a very sensible remark to make.
- This was a surprising decision for them to take.

The last of these provides the pattern for an alternative to the OP's sentence. Namely the inclusion of the subject:

- It is an important thing to *for you (me/him, etc.)* to do.

The CGEL does not explicitly rule out the passive in such constructions. But using the passive here makes the sentences more complex than they need to be. And it makes them sound unnatural to me as a native English speaker.

---

Addendum: A similar question was asked about the first of CGEL's *hollow to-infinitivals* ('*as a complement to predicative adjectives and nouns'*). The answer contains a link to Wikipedia's interesting grammatical feature called *tough movement*.

[To explain or to be explained](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/229711/to-explain-or-to-be-explained)

Comment: You commented 'The only 'rule' is that the passive is unusual in such expressions. For example: It is an easy thing to make (?to be made); It is an important thing to remember (?to be remembered); It is a useful thing to buy (?to be bought); It is a difficult problem to solve (?to be solved).' I'd say these are unidiomatic, but 'He is a good player to be dropped' is borderline acceptable, but with the meaning 'What! ... they're dropping _him_?' This probably goes beyond what CGEL covers, never mind Swan.

Answer (score 0):

This question  has been  taken  from  Michael Swan' s  Practical  English usage   on  page  number 273.

Some times there is  not  much  difference  between  active  and  passive infinitives  when  they  are  used  as  infinitive  complements( to  + infinitive  or  to  + be +  past  participle.)

> **It   is  an important thing   to  do** ( active infinitive)
>
> **It  is  an important thing  to be  done**( 
>     (passive infinitive)

They  are called  active and  passive infinitives  used  as  infinitive  complements.

The   active infinitive  **to do**    may  be

changed to    **to  be  done**  passive infinitive.

Similarly
,

**to make**    is  changed  to   **to be made**

Both  the  sentences  are  correct ,   and mean  the  same  thing

**Michael  Swan  in his  Practical  English  On   page  number   273   under  the title    287     Infinitive  complements  (5) active and  passive infinitive  with  similar  meaning**  gave  this  information.

He  gave  the  following  sentences

> **There is  a  lot  of  work to do/ to be done**.
>
> **There  are six letters  to  contact/ to  be  contacted.**
>
> **Give  me  the names of the people to post/ to be  posted**
>
> **The people to interview / to be interviewed are  in the  next  room**

According to  Michael Swan  all the  four  sentences  above  are  correct  and  mean  the  same thing.z

If  the answer  is  wrong,   I can no longer  depend  on  his book as  it  is  not  being accepted  by  his fellow  country  men  and native  speakers of English and so  it  is  unreliable.

Comment: You can depend on Swan. In the paragraph following the examples you include above, Swan says: _We prefer active infinitives if we are thinking more about the person who will do the action. I've got work to do. (NOT <strike>I've got work to be done.</strike>)_

Comment: @shoe. our  answers  should  base  on  the  question  asked.There  are  many  exceptions  to  every  rule.THERE  is  no change  in meaning  between  active  and  passive  infi.nitives  are  concerned  as far as the  sentences  given  about  OPs sentence or  the  sentences  in Michael Swan' s book.Other  differences  are  not  necessary  here.You  may  depend  your  stand  but  neither      Swan  nor  I  am  wrong  as far as  the  sentences  are  correct.There  is  no  point  in  prolonging  this  discussion.I  am not  wrong  anyway.